Hello, please help us . We revoked admin rights but did not revoke the rights to change metadata,
please help us . We revoked admin rights but did not revoke the rights to change metadata, now we wanted to change the metadata and revoke the rights, but we can’t do it.

You can do this using Tony’s tools here
https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/token-tools/token-management
Please note that this is not reversible

it doesn't let me make changes, it says there's an error

Please send more information. Error message or similar. It's either because the Update Authority is wrong or their is not enough SOL
